# How to monitor cloudfoundry application through web service

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

As you know, cloudfoundry suggest a command tool to push and manage applications. I am asking if there is a native solution (API or Webservices, ... ) that provides similar thing. If yes, please share links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the question here is?

> cloudfoundry suggest a command tool to push and manage applications

There's a CLI tool ('cf') for pushing, stopping and starting applications, yes - and also an Eclipse plugin, and an API.

The title of the question appears to be about monitoring? You can hook an application up to a third-party monitoring solution such as New Relic (Pivotal Web Services / run.pivotal.io, a hosted Cloud Foundry environment, offers 1-click integration with NR).

Comment: What I mean with monitoring is pushing, stopping and starting applications from a third-party application.

Comment: so administering and deploying - there are a number of APIs and wrappers. I recommend the cf-java-client which includes Maven and Gradle plugins for doing exactly this. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client